# Is linker used for simple C programs?

Tags: c, linker

Suppose I have a C source file which does not contain any reference to any other  file. You may assume it only contains -

```
int main(void) {
    int a=5, b=10;
}
```

Will this source file go to the linker? What will be the task of the linker in this case?

Comment: The linker is required to build an executable image for the OS.

Comment: You can't run anything that hasn't been linked.   However, you often don't "see" that the linker is running.  The linker makes the actual machine instructions the CPU executes.  Compilers just make middle-man code for the linker.

Comment: [Here are some good info about linking and executing](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/LG/issue84/hawk.html) and another one from [from wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will because linker will be invoked to form the runnable executable. No matter it's one source file or many, each translation unit will be first compile to object file, and then linked against the C's runtime to form the executable program. So even you see only one source file, it is still linked to the runtime by the linker.

Answer (score 2):

The linker is Always needed, also if you don't use any explicit library. Any program needs anyway to include in his binary the OS basic startup instructions, and the linker add them to your executable